# pandasにてcsvを読み込んだときにカンマで区切られない

Tags: pandas, csv

[image: csv読込]

pandasにてcsvを読み込んだ時にカンマで区切ることができません。
図のように、columnが1と表示されてしまいます。

delimiterも試してみましたが、変化がありません。

何か足りない部分があるのでしょうか？

以下、追記--------------------
3行目と4行目を記載します。
行全体がダブルクォートで囲まれている様には見えないのですが。。

```
DATA No                         ,"DATE"                            ,"TIME"                            ,"INTERVAL"                        ,

     0,2000/11/15,23:24:38,         0,  +0.07622529,
```

Comment: おそらく、行全体がダブルクォートで囲まれているのではないかと思います。

Comment: 使用しているCSVファイルの中身を何行か抜粋して(スクリーンショットではなくテキストで)提示してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: @oriri さん回答のようにプログラム側で対策するのも手でしょうが、そもそもそのCSVファイルを作る側とか受け取る際にCSVの仕様に従っているかどうかチェックや対策をしてみてはどうでしょう？ CSVのバリデーションツール等は探せば複数あるようですのでお好みのものを使えば良いと思われます。

Comment: ちょっと検索してみたらPythonでこんなのがあったので使えるかもしれません。[csvkit 1.0.7](https://pypi.org/project/csvkit/), [csvkitの使い方まとめ](https://qiita.com/okiyuki99/items/d5add3aa062bf4f10cad)

Answer (score 2):

最初に余分な行が入ってて, 1カラムとみなされてるようです
`skiprows=` を指定してください (余分な行数)

```py
import pandas as pd
import io
csv = io.StringIO('''
title
aaa,bbb,cccc,dddd
100,200,300,400
'''.strip())

pd.read_csv(csv, skiprows=1)
#    aaa  bbb  cccc  dddd
# 0  100  200   300   400
```